# MySQL Brute Force Defense

Tags: mysql, security

I was wondering what defense MySQL server uses to protect against brute force attacks on the user credentials? I hope this isn't too simple of a question! I have tried to Google it, but can't seem to find really any clear cut answer.

Comment: do they authenticate directly w the db, or with your web server?

Comment: Directly with the DB

Comment: You could try monitoring mysql log with fail2ban https://brain.demonpenguin.co.uk/2014/05/01/fail2ban-monitoring-mysql/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL security hasn't been every a particular strong point of the server software. That is why most people recommend **not expose the MySQL port outside** the internal network/firewall. Like any other software, there has been [records of vulnerabilities found](http://seclists.org/oss-sec/2012/q2/493).

Having said that, MySQL has a basic protection against port-scan attacks, as it maintains internally a list of blocked hosts and it adds a host to this list when more than 10/100 TCP/IP connections are interrupted ([max_connect_errors](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_connect_errors)). Please note that this is not a real brute-force attack protection, as both a [successful and an unsuccessful complete connection will reset the counter](http://mysqlblog.fivefarmers.com/2013/08/08/understanding-max_connect_errors/) and `localhost` is whitelisted.

Comment: Thank you very much for such a detailed answer! I always close the MySQL port outside of the firewall, but I was wondering what would happen if I didn't.